# nRF52 Bootloader over ESP12E

Tags: esp8266, bootloader, swd, hex-file, nrf52832

I'm using nRF52 DK with 14.2.0 SDK. I created a LED blink project for testing and extract its HEX file. I uploaded the program to the nRF52 over USB (J-Link-Keil IDE) and the HEX file over ESP12E (SWD) to compare the register values between the working one (USB) and the non-working one (SWD). There is no difference between them. I could not understand why its not working when I uploaded the code over ESP12E. Isn't it enough to just write the hex file into nrf memory. I did some search on the web but I could not find any solutions working for me. Waiting for your replies. Thanks in advance,

Comment: This seems a little mixed up.  The nrf52832 has no USB interface.  The j-link would be using SWD.  It's not clear *what* you were doing with the ESP12E.  Without full details that make sense, your question is unanswerable, though doing a full erase and loading only your custom program but not the softdevice could be a guess.

Comment: nrf52dk(dev-board) has usb interface and swd header. 2 case: 1-Upload code with usb (Keil is handle all things in this way). 2- esp8266 is download hex file from server, edit file and upload it to nrf. No, file doesn't include Softdevice. Thanks for advices.

Comment: The problem is you've provided no information about what the esp upload actually does, beyond erroneously identifying it as SWD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by the asker in unanswerable form